# How to make drag from NSButton in MacOS Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, drag-and-drop

I have NSButton what accepts drop on to add dragged items to NSMutableArray. How can I make drag from NSButton to drag all items in NSMutableArray?

Comment: Could you explain further please? After you drop the items on the button, do you want to know how to get them into an array, or are you asking how to drag them back out of the button?

Comment: I'm already getting them into an array after drop. I don't know how to drag them back out of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to use the NSView method, dragImage:at:offset:event:pasteboard:source:slideBack: to start the drag.  In your custom button class you would override mouseDown: and call that method.  I  wrote an example where the image that's dragged is the button's image, and the data I'm dragging is just the string "ARRAY".  That should be all you need to do from the source side -- when you drop that on your destination, it could test to see if what was dropped was the string "ARRAY" and then do whatever you want to do with that array you created with your first drop. I used the NSMultipleDocuments image in my button, and I make it disappear when I drag out of the button.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
     NSImage *pic = self.image;
     NSSize dragOffset = NSMakeSize(0.0, 0.0);
     NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType]  owner:self];
    [pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ARRAY"]];
    NSPoint btnMiddle = NSMakePoint(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2);
    NSPoint picOrigin = NSMakePoint(btnMiddle.x - pic.size.width/2, btnMiddle.y + pic.size.height/2);
    self.image = nil;
    [self dragImage:pic at:picOrigin offset:dragOffset event:theEvent pasteboard:pboard source:self slideBack:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's works, but with one trouble - now i can't click on button to call `clickAction`.

Comment: I think that might be tricky to do -- I tried adding [super mouseDown:theEvent] and that sort of worked, but it only seemed to work every other time (and if you click first instead of drag, the image disappears).  Why do you want to drag the items onto a button any way, that seems kind of odd to me?

Comment: Button opens window with table (with drag'n'drop support). But I also want drag'n'drop to/from button without opening this window. Table used for displaying ARRAY content.

Comment: I don't think I know how to make that work with a simple button -- you might have to make a more complex control that has a drop zone to do the drag&drop, while the rest of the control would act as a button.